# sk_buff->tstamp in java is possible?

Tags: java, kernel

I am trying to get the timestamp of received packets in `Java`. The timestamp must be as accurate as possible. Consequenty, I should get it from the `sk_buff kernel structure`.

Is possible to get this value in `Java` (userspace) or it is only available in `kernelspace`?

I've been trying to search on the net but nothing come up.

Thanks in advance,
McD0n3ld

Comment: How about reading the packet using libpcap (e.g. using pcap4j) instead?